# Need to run live clock of different time zones within the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timezone, clock

I am getting multiple times of multiple time zones by the multiple users in the same condition by which they are fetched by a foreach loop. Now I have to run these times as a live clock in real time without load a complete page. I had used reload function, setInterval function, many of js for update these several times but it is not working properly. Please suggest.

```
 foreach($total_acvite_members as $acvite_members){
   if(!empty($user_obj->timezone)){
     $local_time = $user_obj->timezone;
     $newTZ = new DateTimeZone("$local_time");
     $date = new DateTime($local_time );
     $date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
     print "<span id='timing'>".format_date(time(), 'custom', 'h:i a D, M - Y')."</span>";
     //print $date->format('h:i a D, M - Y');
   }else{
      print '<span>Not Available</span>';
    }
```

}

Comment: This issue has been fixed by using this code (http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mQrJn/) with some changes in codes and also changes in the template file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript or jQuery world time clocks like this
[jQuery World Clock](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Based-Analog-And-Digital-World-Clock-jClocksGMT-js.html)

They can display multiple clocks on the page. Go through how they use time and date data to display a clock properly. Then push your retrieved data into their code and fine tune.

Comment: I have used this, but not working as I want.
Suggest another method.

Comment: @KumarAshutosh Without knowing exactly how you want, how to suggest another method ? The plugin suggested matched your description. "Not working as I want" does not convey any clarity.